# Are fungible states automatically merged on Corda?

Tags: corda

I want to create a custom fungible asset on corda.. It is unclear to me how states that implement FungibleAsset are handled internally. Say I receive ten 1 dollar CoinStates from a transaction, are those merged to one 10 dollar Coinstate which I then use as the one and only input state if I wanted to make a payment myself?

basically I want something like the Cash.generateSpend which unfortunately is not very well documented

My approach so far for a transferFlow:

I have a function that does a vault query and should return some parties balance.. (this is assuming that the balance amount is internally merged to one state)

then using this balance as Input state I have a check if the input is equal the amount to pay in which case I will simply create one output state of the same amount but a new owner, otherwise I create another output state with the amount of change and myself as the owner

This is the function so far...
    I have a function that does a vault query and should return some parties balance..

```
StateAndRef<CurrencyState> getBalaceOfIdentiy(AbstractParty id) throws FlowException {
    QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.FungibleAssetQueryCriteria(null,ImmutableList.of(id),null, null,
    null, null, null
    );
    // this assumes states are merged internally
    List<StateAndRef<CurrencyState>> balanceOfID = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(CurrencyState.class, queryCriteria).getStates();
    return balanceOfID.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Corda follows UTXO model. I'm not sure which version of Corda you are on but if you'll look closely enough you'll find that it would call `OnLedgerAsset.generateSpend` at some point of time and that does the job for you. and can be statically used as it is annotated with `@JvmStatic`.